# How can I parse this JSON in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Please help me parse this json in ruby:

```
"\"{\\\"Details\\\":[{\\\"WaybillNo\\\":\\\"11-17-657\\\",\\\"ShipperName\\\":\\\"Paritosh Singh\\\",\\\"ShipperAddress\\\":\\\"New Delhi, India\\\",\\\"ShipperMob\\\":\\\"0812944\\\",\\\"ConsigneeName\\\":\\\"SANDY\\\",\\\"ConsigneeAddress\\\":\\\"Mumbai India\\\",\\\"ConsigneeMob\\\":\\\"8355485\\\",\\\"Pieces\\\":\\\"1\\\"}]}\""
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like JSON within JSON:

```
require 'json'

string = "\"{\\\"Details\\\":[{\\\"WaybillNo\\\":\\\"11-17-657\\\",\\\"ShipperName\\\":\\\"Paritosh Singh\\\",\\\"ShipperAddress\\\":\\\"New Delhi, India\\\",\\\"ShipperMob\\\":\\\"0812944\\\",\\\"ConsigneeName\\\":\\\"SANDY\\\",\\\"ConsigneeAddress\\\":\\\"Mumbai India\\\",\\\"ConsigneeMob\\\":\\\"8355485\\\",\\\"Pieces\\\":\\\"1\\\"}]}\""

JSON.parse(JSON.parse(string))
#=> {
#     "Details" => [
#       [0] {
#         "WaybillNo"        => "11-17-657",
#         "ShipperName"      => "Paritosh Singh",
#         "ShipperAddress"   => "New Delhi, India",
#         "ShipperMob"       => "0812944",
#         "ConsigneeName"    => "SANDY",
#         "ConsigneeAddress" => "Mumbai India",
#         "ConsigneeMob"     => "8355485",
#         "Pieces"           => "1"
#       }
#     ]
#   }
```

Comment: Not on my machine. Did you `require 'json'`? What version of Ruby do you use? What error does it raise?

Comment: Yup, I did require json. I am using ruby version 2.4.1

Comment: I am geeting this error:
JSON::ParserError: 784: unexpected token at '"{\"Details\":[{\"WaybillNo\":\"11-17-657\",\"ShipperName\":\"Paritosh Singh\",\"ShipperAddress\":\"New Delhi, India\",\"ShipperMob\":\"0812944\",\"ConsigneeName\":\"SANDY\",\"ConsigneeAddress\":\"Mumbai India\",\"ConsigneeMob\":\"8355485\",\"Pieces\":\"1\"}]}"'

Comment: I get the same error with the string provided, but the string provided in the question works fine. Where did the first string come from and how did you generate the second string?

Comment: I am using same string as given in question :)

Comment: The other string has a different level of \\ escaping

Comment: Found a way to parse json:
JSON.parse(string.gsub("\"","").gsub("\\","\""))